# Shortest way to convert bool value to its string representation (e.g. 'true')

Tags: javascript

Basically I need to convert a 'boolean' type value into its equivalent as a string (`true` or `false`) and I am wondering whether there is a shorter (even if its slower) way than doing `boolVal ? 'true' : 'false`?

So is there a shorter way to accomplish the following? All ES2015-2018 goodies can be used if it helps :)

```
const boolVal = true
const boolStr = boolVal ? 'true' : 'false'
```

**EDIT:** I created a small benchmark of the presented solutions. https://jsperf.com/bool-to-string-conversion

[image: benchmark of bool to string conversion]

Comment: Did you try `toString()`?

Comment: There are shorter ways, but they're not cleaner (i.e. `''+boolVal`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codegolf.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `toString()` on the variable to get its string equivalent:

```js
var a = true.toString();
var b = false.toString();

console.log(a, b, typeof a, typeof b);
```

Comment: Not worth its own answer, but `String(theBoolean)` is in the same vein.

Comment: String(bool) uses .toString and it's safer if we deal with null or undefined values

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String()` as a function

```js
const t = String(true)
const f = String(false)

console.log(t, f, typeof t, typeof f);
```

**EDIT**

`String()` is slower than `toString()`

```js
const time = 10000000

  console.time('toString')
  for(let i =0 ; i< time; i++)
    true.toString()
  console.timeEnd('toString')

  console.time('String(bool)')
  for(let i =0 ; i< time; i++)
    String(true)
  console.timeEnd('String(bool)')
```

But... What if we are not sure that our boolean value exist?

```js
const u = undefined;
const n = null;

// String()
console.log('String( undefined ): ', String(u), typeof String(n));
console.log('String( null ): ', String(n), typeof String(n));

// toString() :) 

console.log( u.toString() );
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work i think:

```
boolStr = boolVal.toString()
```

Edit: I tested and it works. 
https://jsbin.com/bapuvoqibo/edit?html,console,output

You can check out this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/toString

Comment: "i think" ? Why not test it ? (btw this was a comment long ago)

Comment: Yes I tested and it works. Can you please check it out here: https://jsbin.com/bapuvoqibo/edit?html,console,output